# Grails urlMappings action and controller behavior not using controller logic

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp, grails-controller

I have a grails app where the content of `urlMappings.groovy` file is:

```
"/" {
   controller="home" 
   view="home"
}
```

My home controller looks like

```
class HomeController {
   List products = [
      ['price': 100, 'desc':'a'],
      ['price': 200, 'desc':'b']
   ]

   def home() {
      [products: products]
   }
```

When I navigate to `localhost:8080/myProject/home/home`, I have access to `"${products}"`, but when I navigate to `localhost:8080/myProject`, `"${products}"` statement is null.

Why is this and how can I make the `localhost:8080/myProject` act the same way as `localhost:8080/myProject/home/home`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do

```
"/"(controller: 'home', action: 'home')
```

Comment: Woops! Had view not action in the name, that's what caused it.